# How to pass statically typed argument in thunk-action?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

In my react app I have created a ThunkAction with the help of Action Creator. It looks like this -

```
export const oneMoreAsyncThunkAction: ActionCreator< ThunkAction<void, IChatState, {}, ToggleOnlineStateAction >> = (payload: boolean) => {
    return (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<IChatState, {}, ToggleOnlineStateAction >, getState, extraArguement): void => {
      try {        
          const promise = new Promise<ToggleOnlineStateAction>((resolve, reject) =>{
              setTimeout(() => {
                  resolve({
                    type: TOGGLE_ONLINE_STATE,
                    payload: payload
                });
              }, 1000);
          })
          promise.then(action => {
              dispatch(action)
          });
      } catch (e) {}
    };
  };
```

I am expecting a boolean argument `(payload)` in my action.

In another file, I am using this action like this -

```
let action = ChatActions.oneMoreAsyncThinkAction(!props.isOnline);
dispatch(action);
```

I was expecting that VSCode will suggest me to pass a boolean value as an argument in the action. But it suggests that `...any[]` values can be passed in the argument.

[image]

I want my Action to be statically typed. How could I fix my code so that VSCode suggest me to pass boolean value in the Action.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer here is to use [the `createAsyncThunk` API from our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk), which is written in TS and strongly typed:

```js
const toggleOnline = createAsyncThunk(
  'chat/toggleOnline',
  async (online: boolean) => {
    await sleep(1000); // use a common util function here
    return online; // becomes the success action payload
  }
)

// later
dispatch(toggleOnline(!isOnline));
```